# How to update references to SyntaxNode's in SymbolInfo after adding annotations?

Tags: c#, roslyn

On first stage I am adding annotations to syntax nodes and replace nodes with new generated nodes.

On second stage when I am analysing modified document (same syntax tree with added annotations) but references in SymbolInfo still refers to unmodified syntax nodes (without annotations).

Is it possible to update or reparse solution or project and update SymbolInfo after adding annotations?

Create simple solution with one C# file:

```
class С
{
    void g()
    { }

    void f()
    {
        g();
    }
}
```

And try to parse it with program:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Roslyn.Compilers;
using Roslyn.Compilers.Common;
using Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp;
using Roslyn.Services;

namespace RoslynExample2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var workspace = Workspace.LoadSolution(@"..\..\..\..\RoslynExampleTest\RoslynExampleTest.sln");
            var solution = workspace.CurrentSolution;

            foreach (var project in solution.Projects)
            {
                Annotator annotator = new Annotator();
                foreach (var document in project.Documents)
                {
                    CompilationUnitSyntax compilationUnit = (CompilationUnitSyntax)document.GetSyntaxRoot();
                    var mcu = annotator.AddAnnotations(compilationUnit);
                    document.UpdateSyntaxRoot(mcu);
                }
            }

            foreach (var project in solution.Projects)
            {
                foreach (var document in project.Documents)
                {
                    var compilationUnit = document.GetSyntaxRoot();
                    var semanticModel = document.GetSemanticModel();

                    MySyntaxWalker sw = new MySyntaxWalker(semanticModel);
                    sw.Visit((SyntaxNode)compilationUnit);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    internal class Annotator
    {
        internal struct SyntaxNodeTuple
        {
            internal SyntaxNode Origin;
            internal SyntaxNode Modified;

            internal SyntaxNodeTuple(SyntaxNode origin, SyntaxNode modified)
            {
                Origin = origin;
                Modified = modified;
            }
        }

        private SyntaxNodeTuple AddAnnotation(SyntaxNode s)
        {
            SyntaxNodeTuple t;

            switch (s.Kind)
            {
                case SyntaxKind.ClassDeclaration:
                    t = AddAnnotations((ClassDeclarationSyntax)s);
                    break;
                case SyntaxKind.MethodDeclaration:
                    t = AddAnnotations((MethodDeclarationSyntax)s);
                    break;
                default:
                    t = new SyntaxNodeTuple();
                    break;
            }

            return t;
        }

        private static T ReplaceNodes<T>(T d, List<SyntaxNodeTuple> tuples)
            where T : SyntaxNode
        {
            T d2 = d;
            foreach (var t in tuples)
            {
                d2 = d2.ReplaceNode(t.Origin, t.Modified);
            }
            return d2;
        }

        private void AddAnnotationsToList(SyntaxList<MemberDeclarationSyntax> list, List<SyntaxNodeTuple> tuples)
        {
            foreach (var m in list)
            {
                tuples.Add(AddAnnotation(m));
            }
        }

        internal CompilationUnitSyntax AddAnnotations(CompilationUnitSyntax d)
        {
            List<SyntaxNodeTuple> tuples = new List<SyntaxNodeTuple>();
            AddAnnotationsToList(d.Members, tuples);
            var d2 = ReplaceNodes(d, tuples);
            return d2;
        }

        internal SyntaxNodeTuple AddAnnotations(ClassDeclarationSyntax d)
        {
            List<SyntaxNodeTuple> tuples = new List<SyntaxNodeTuple>();
            AddAnnotationsToList(d.Members, tuples);
            var d2 = ReplaceNodes(d, tuples);
            d2 = d2.WithAdditionalAnnotations(new MyAnnotation());
            return new SyntaxNodeTuple(d, d2);
        }

        internal SyntaxNodeTuple AddAnnotations(MethodDeclarationSyntax d)
        {
            var d2 = d.WithAdditionalAnnotations(new MyAnnotation());

            bool hasAnnotation = d2.HasAnnotations(typeof(MyAnnotation)); // annotation exists

            return new SyntaxNodeTuple(d, d2);
        }
    }

    class MyAnnotation : SyntaxAnnotation
    { }

    partial class MySyntaxWalker : SyntaxWalker
    {
        private ISemanticModel _semanticModel;

        public MySyntaxWalker(ISemanticModel semanticModel)
        {
            _semanticModel = semanticModel;
        }

        public override void VisitInvocationExpression(InvocationExpressionSyntax decl)
        {
            var si = _semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(decl);
            var dsns = si.Symbol.DeclaringSyntaxNodes;
            var dsn0 = dsns[0];
            bool hasAnnotation = dsn0.HasAnnotations(typeof(MyAnnotation));  // annotation doesn't exists
        }
    }
}
```

updated variant:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Roslyn.Compilers;
using Roslyn.Compilers.Common;
using Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp;
using Roslyn.Services;

namespace RoslynExample2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var workspace = Workspace.LoadSolution(@"..\..\..\..\RoslynExampleTest\RoslynExampleTest.sln");
            var solution = workspace.CurrentSolution;

            foreach (var projectId in solution.ProjectIds)
            {
                var project = solution.GetProject(projectId);
                foreach (var documentId in project.DocumentIds)
                {
                    var document = project.GetDocument(documentId);
                    CompilationUnitSyntax compilationUnit = (CompilationUnitSyntax)document.GetSyntaxRoot();
                    Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("compilationUnit={0} before", compilationUnit.GetHashCode()));
                    Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("project={0} before", project.GetHashCode()));
                    Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("solution={0} before", solution.GetHashCode()));
                    var mcu = new AnnotatorSyntaxRewritter().Visit(compilationUnit);
                    var project2 = document.UpdateSyntaxRoot(mcu).Project;
                    if (mcu != compilationUnit)
                    {
                        solution = project2.Solution;
                    }
                    Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("compilationUnit={0} after", mcu.GetHashCode()));
                    Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("project={0} after", project2.GetHashCode()));
                    Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("solution={0} after", solution.GetHashCode()));
                }
            }

            foreach (var projectId in solution.ProjectIds)
            {
                var project = solution.GetProject(projectId);
                foreach (var documentId in project.DocumentIds)
                {
                    var document = project.GetDocument(documentId);
                    var compilationUnit = document.GetSyntaxRoot();
                    var semanticModel = document.GetSemanticModel();
                    Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("compilationUnit={0} stage", compilationUnit.GetHashCode()));
                    Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("project={0} stage", project.GetHashCode()));
                    Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("solution={0}", solution.GetHashCode()));

                    MySyntaxWalker sw = new MySyntaxWalker(semanticModel);
                    sw.Visit((SyntaxNode)compilationUnit);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class AnnotatorSyntaxRewritter : SyntaxRewriter
    {
        public override SyntaxNode VisitMethodDeclaration(MethodDeclarationSyntax node)
        {
            node = node.WithAdditionalAnnotations(new MyAnnotation());
            return base.VisitMethodDeclaration(node);
        }
    }

    class MyAnnotation : SyntaxAnnotation
    { }

    partial class MySyntaxWalker : SyntaxWalker
    {
        private ISemanticModel _semanticModel;

        public MySyntaxWalker(ISemanticModel semanticModel)
        {
            _semanticModel = semanticModel;
        }

        public override void VisitMethodDeclaration(MethodDeclarationSyntax decl)
        {
            bool hasAnnotation = decl.HasAnnotations(typeof(MyAnnotation));
            Debug.Assert(hasAnnotation);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the code where you add the annotation?  Do you get a new Compilation and SemanticModel after adding the annotations?

Comment: Yes, I get documents and semantic model again after calling IDocument.UpdateSyntaxRoot(). I will add minimal code to reproduce problem ASAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your example is that the variable `solution` is an immutable object which refers to the solution when it is first loaded.  In your code where you call `document.UpdateSyntaxRoot(mcu)`, that actually creates and returns a new `IDocument` which is in a new `IProject`, which is in a new `ISolution`.

Try changing that bit of code to:

```
Annotator annotator = new Annotator();
foreach (var projectId in solution.ProjectIds)
{
    foreach (var documentId in solution.GetProject(projectId).DocumentIds)
    {
        var document = solution.GetProject(projectId).GetDocument(documentId);
        CompilationUnitSyntax compilationUnit = (CompilationUnitSyntax)document.GetSyntaxRoot();
        var mcu = annotator.AddAnnotations(compilationUnit);
        solution = document.UpdateSyntaxRoot(mcu).Project.Solution;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Kevin. You are very helps me.

Comment: Hello Kevin. One more question. If project contains 2 C# files and if in first file AST was modified and in second file AST was not modified then document.UpdateSyntaxRoot(mcu).Project for the second file returns reference to unmodified solution.

Comment: That is by design.  If you update with the same root, we return the same solution so as to avoid needless allocations.  If you want a "fresh" solution instance in that case, you can use Solution.Clone().

Comment: I am just want to add annotation to every method and type in all projects and documents. And after that I want to get reference to solution that contains all modifications. But i still can't write correct example to do that (See update version). Firstly, I tryed to ignore value returned by document.UpdateSyntaxRoot(mcu) if syntax root is not modified but this doesn't help. Could you tell when I must call Solution.Clone() to solve the problem?

Comment: You do not seen to call Solution.Clone().  The issue was another subtle immutability issue.  The problem is that in the inner loop, the document is always being retrieved from the original project, not the project that is updated with the new document.  I've updated my code example to one that should work when there are multiple documents in the projects.